# Installing Adobe Flashplayer on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, flash, flash-player

I'm running Ubntu 9.04, and had adobe flash and air running fine (which meant I had my beloved tweetdeck). Then I ran the system janitor, and tweetdeck went away. Since then, I've been unable to get flash running again. It looks like I've installed it correctly, the test page at adobe shows flash running, but whenever I try to play flash content it tells me I'm missing a plugin (but won't let me install it). Any thoughts? I've already run system updates and the like.

Comment: The title is misleading. Someone might want to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried first uninstalling and then reinstalling?

[Try this:](http://osdir.com/ml/linux.ubuntu.user.edubuntu/2007-08/msg00280.html)

> Take a look in
>   /usr/lib/firefox/plugins and see
>   what's there. There may  be a sym link
>   to Flash 7 (especially if you upgraded
>   a distro that  already had it
>   installed). Remove that sym link (or
>   .so file), and all  should be well.
>   You can then install the latest
>   version, and it should  be the only
>   one recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is installed?  This should properly install flash across the system (including the Firefox plugin).

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It was already current.

Comment: Try with the `--reinstall` flag?