# TweetDeck Adobe air on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, adobe-air

Getting an odd error with TweetDeck

> tweetdeckfast.fff259dc0ce2657847bbb4aff0e62062efc56543.1
>   : PreDepends: adobeair (>= 1.5.3.0)
>   but it is not installable

It fixes the problem by deleting tweetdeck.  I've tried a few things on ubuntu forums none seem to work well.

Comment: Migrate to http://askubuntu.com/, it probably has better answers.

Comment: If all you're going to do is pass it around, it would be nice to at least link to the new location.  Second time this was passed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Adobe Flashplayer on Ubuntu](http://superuser.com/questions/18587/installing-adobe-flashplayer-on-ubuntu)